# Attach files to send via email By EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I need to send an email with few attachments to different clients. The attachments are put on different folders, each one named by the name.

For example..

```
In column "A" = Clients name
In column "B" = Clientes emails
In column "C" = The subject
In column "D" = The email body (ex: Hello, here the attachemtn)
In column "E" = The folder where the attachemtns are on
```

I need to have one routine for each cliente ( +- 14 clientes ).
Noting having any success on this.
Any help?

Sub SendEMAIL()

```
Dim MyOlapp As Object, MeuItem As Object
Set MyOlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MeuItem = MyOlapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With MeuItem
.to = Range("A2")
.Subject = Range("D2")
.Body = "Range("C2")

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script I use for Outlook to send an email with attachments...

```
Sub NLANghtRpt()
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments

 'location of your files
myPath1 = "C:\Users\username\Documents\"


Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With myItem
    .To = "whoever you want to send to"  
    .CC = "whoever you want to copy"
    .Subject = "your subject here"
    .Body = "NIGHTLY REPORT FOR  " & Format(Now, "mm.dd.yy")
      ' I use the previous line for a generic message with a time stamp

 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments

myAttachments.Add myPath1 & ("ReportSchedule.xls")
myAttachments.Add myPath1 & ("ReportBooks.xls")
myAttachments.Add myPath1 & ("ReportHours.xls")


 myItem.Display
 End With
End Sub
```

Of course, edit to fit your environment. Good luck